# WinAppDriver: Unable to connect to the remote server in Local Session

Tags: vb.net, winappdriver

I am attempting to use WinAppDriver to test a classic Windows form control application on a local PC.  This test is to run all on the same PC executing the code, not remotely.

However, when attempting to launch the application with WinAppDriver, the following ex occurs:

Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I found where, for WinAppDriver, that Windows must be set to "Developer Mode", and I already have that turned on.

Here's the code I have so far, just using the Notepad.exe example for now:

```
Dim appCapabilities As DesiredCapabilities = New DesiredCapabilities()
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
Dim NotepadSession As New WindowsDriver(Of WindowsElement)(New Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities)
```

The ex is thrown on the third line.

Answer (score 0):

WinAppDriver was not actually running at the time of executing this code.  I was incorrectly assuming that it was already running.

Running it beforehand resolved the error completely, and Notepad launched.